# If time is like space, why entropy always increases with time?

Tags: thermodynamics, spacetime, entropy, relativity, arrow-of-time

If time is like space, why entropy always increases with time

I should not be able to distinguish whether I am going forwards or backwards in time.

As entropy always increase with time. I can distinguish past from future in a four dimensional space-time.

Edit:

It looks like, it is an unresolved problem http://youtu.be/9VFGuupXwng
There are some solutions http://youtu.be/RwYcPra40CY but nothing generally acceptable

Comment: who said that time is like space? they may be treated "together" in a geometric object called spacetime, but they do not behave in the same way (for example, you can stay still in space, but not in time)

Comment: Entropy is not an universal clock _de jure_ ... it grows so-so like the time and some wonder if it is **the** clock ... not obvious answer without some beliefs

Answer (score 2):

1. Time is not like space. It is a coordinate, as the space coordinates, but that doesn't mean it is the same.
2. Read Ben Crowell's answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20401/is-a-world-with-constant-decreasing-entropy-theoretically-impossible). Entropy is stochastic, it doesn't have to increase monotonously. The very low current universe entropy can make the illusion that it always does, but there is still a very low probability that it decreases for a short time.