# Is entropy increase in disorder or 'energy-dispersal'?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

My teacher explained entropy like this:

> **It is increase in disorderliness.**
>
> Take a glass jar put three layers of blue marbles in it then put three further layer of red marbles, now shake the jar, after some time you will find all the marbles get mixed up equally, after this, however much you shake there will *NEVER* be a time when the blue marbles come back to their original position and the red marbles to theirs.

The mixing of the marbles to a maximum extent is the highest entropy, and it always increases until it reaches its maximum, if you have to decrease entropy you have to introduce some external force.

And this is what I have read else where

[Entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy)

[Entropy: Disorder or energy dispersal?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/176469/entropy-disorder-or-energy-dispersal)

Although it doesn't seem to contradict but I want to confirm if this is the right analogy for the explanation?

Comment: Search for "entropy disorder" in the search box up and to the left, and many, many questions on this site will come up on this very topic.