# Entropy and Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution

Tags: entropy

I am quite confused about Entropy.

If we look at the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution of a gas we see a higher temperature gas is more spread out than a lower temperature gas.  The hotter gas covers a much bigger range of velocities.

The hotter gas also has more entropy.  Can we say that the hotter gas has more entropy because of this wider range of velocities?  I really don't know if they are related or not, but it does seem that the wider range does make it more "disorderly"

Answer (score 2):

Here, you are relating two concepts: one where the law of thermodynamics are steadfast and logical and one where those laws are meaningless and instead statistics is key.

This is the difference between **Thermodynamic Entropy** and **Informational Entropy**.

From the point of view of the Second Law of Thermodynamics, the answer is simple: higher temperature gasses have faster moving particles and thus greater **changes** in entropy.

From the point of view of Informational Entropy, we care about the probability and positions of particles - at a macroscopic scale. So, if a gas' particles possess larger velocities, they theoretically have a greater number of positions to occupy than a gas with slower particles. This would mean that the higher temperature gas has more entropy than the lower temperature gas.

To answer your question: Yes, you can say the hotter gas has more entropy due to a wider range of velocities, but there are two approaches to concluding so.

I advise that you read up on entropy as it is a misleading topic with the "order" and "disorder" approach versus statistical. "joseph f. johnson" had a spectacular analogy and answer that was understandable and very informational.

Here is the link to his answer:
[Clear up confusion about the meaning of entropy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/66651/clear-up-confusion-about-the-meaning-of-entropy?rq=1)