# Exact definition of entropy

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, definition

Sometimes it is described as a state of disorder and sometimes it is called the inavalability of the thermal of energy of the system to do mechanical work.

So

> How exactly is entropy defined?

Also, how does it explain why time flows in one direction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clear up confusion about the meaning of entropy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/66651/)

Comment: Or this: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/235511/

Comment: Yes @hft ,it does clear my doubt...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two different definitions of "entropy" in use today. The "right" definition depends on the specific field of interest in which the term arises.

*Shannon entropy* is defined in the realm of *information science*, and *thermodynamic entropy* is defined in the realm of thermophysics or *heat engine design*.

The answers to your questions depend on what type of entropy you mean.

Comment: ive used the thermodynamics tag